# Canvas works only in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm developping a small game using HTML5's canvas and Javascript. It works great on Chrome but doesn't work in both Firefox and IE9/IE10.

Below's my HTML code, I've included the  tag and X-UA-Compatibility tag, even when removing/changing location doesn't do anything. When putting an alert into the script it does get loaded, but it just won't draw anything on my canvas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />s
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Game</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>    


<img src="images/lovebg1.jpg" alt="background" id="bg" />
<div id="back"> 
 <canvas id="canvas"> 
  <p>Your browser doesn't support Canvas</p>
</canvas></div>
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="content">
<div id="biigheart"></div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>  
    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is useless to us, you need to post the script code.  Also, are you getting any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: It will depend on the version of the browser's your trying. also there might be something wrong with your javascript. Have you checker the error console? can you post the bit of code that takes the canvas, initializes it and draws something on it? You also have a trailing "s" on your meta tags, and should include the jquery plugin on the bottom of the page, not on the head